# Validating Auth0 Token - Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, auth0

I am validating auth0 token in spring boot app with the help of [this official doc](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/01-authorization#protect-api-endpoints)

While running the app, it is throwing below exception

```
2021-11-03 19:12:09.669  WARN 18128 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoder' defined in class path resource [com/talenlio/common/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://dummy/api"
```

My ultimate goal is to validate auth0 token that I'm receiving from frontend.

application.yaml

```
spring:
 security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://my-domain-at.auth0.com/

auth0:
  grantType: client_credentials
  audience: https://dummy/api
  clientId: XXXXXXXXX
  clientSecret: YYYYY
  applicationDomain: https://my-domain-at.auth0.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you followed the spec for `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri`:

> The value will be your Auth0 domain with an https:// prefix and a / suffix (the trailing slash is important).

It's "https://dummy/api/" instead of "https://dummy/api"

Comment: tried this not working, according to document only issuer url is having trailing slash

Comment: I saw you trace log `2021-11-03 19:12:09.669  WARN 18128 --- [           main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://dummy/api"`, that's why I think `"https://dummy/api/"` is your domain. Are you sure that, you put it right? like `issuer-uri: https://YOUR_DOMAIN/`, `Spring` base on your `issuer-uri` + `.well-known/jwks.json` to discover the authorization server's public keys and validate the JWT signature. You could check this link `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/jwks.json` by your browser in order to see a list of keys.